# deny anonymous for all pages except the "~/" path in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, authorization, membership

in asp.net, i use this config section to deny anonymous users for all pages.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

and i use the following to declare an exception that anonymous can access.

```
<location path="Welcome.aspx">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

that works fine for me.

however, how can i set only the default page as an exception?
(such as: anonymous can access only http://mysite/, but can NOT access any other pages in the site?)

i'v tried use location path="~/" or "/" and it doesn't work.

Comment: Assuming your default page is default.aspx, just use that instead of welcome.aspx. It should handle it when it's accessed at the root.

Comment: thanks @doozer-blake, but I want let anonymous users access http:/ /mysite/ without *default.aspx". the only workaround by now i found is allow all users for the whole site and deny users in *any* other locations one by one

Comment: Understood, but it's not picking that up from setting default.aspx? I can run a site locally with the exact setup and it allows anonymous to / or /default.aspx.

Comment: i tried again it won't works for me. i think maybe because i am use asp.net MVC, and my home page is Home/Index, where location="Home/Index" doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `path="Default.aspx"` doesn't work then it cannot be done using configuration. There's no syntax available to specify only the application root in the path attribute.

Comment: thanks. Maybe Default.aspx works in asp.net Pages. However, i am using ASP.NET MVC, any ideas?

Comment: UrlAuthorizationModule executes before MVC Authorization (using Authorize attribute) and because you are using `<deny users="?"/>` as default you'll never see the home page unless you are logged in. Maybe if you write your own UrlAuthorizationModule.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can change your folder structre to achieve this. Then you can change the `web.config` to deny user

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow roles="administrators" />
            <deny users="?" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```